# How to transfer every three lines into columns in R or linux

Tags: r, bash

My input is:

```
"name_01"
"name_02"
 0.000573033 0.001268718  0.45 6.5e-01
"name_03"
"name_04"
 0.00343343 0.0012435358  0.33 7.5e-09`
```

Expected output in tsv:

```
"name_01"    "name_02"    0.0005    0.0019    0.45    6.5e-01
"name_03"    "name_04"    0.0034    0.0012    0.33    7.5e-09
```

Can anyone help in R or linux?

Comment: With paste you can do `paste - - - -d '\t' < file`

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming this input:

```
s <- '"name_01"
"name_02"
 0.000573033 0.001268718  0.45 6.5e-01
"name_03"
"name_04"
 0.00343343 0.0012435358  0.33 7.5e-09'
```

**1)** Read it in using a `what` list and `multi.line=TRUE` scan arguments producing a list `L`; set its names and convert to a data.frame:

```
L <- scan(textConnection(s), what = list("", "", 0, 0, 0, 0), 
       multi.line = TRUE, quiet = TRUE)
names(L) <- paste0("V", seq_along(L))
do.call(data.frame, c(L, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

giving:

```
       V1      V2          V3          V4   V5      V6
1 name_01 name_02 0.000573033 0.001268718 0.45 6.5e-01
2 name_03 name_04 0.003433430 0.001243536 0.33 7.5e-09
```

**2)**   This alternative also uses scan but instead of what using `what` and `list` we reshape it ourself into a matrix, convert that to a data.frame and make the last 4 columns numeric.  If your input actually comes from a file replace `textConnection(s)` with something like `"myfile.txt".  Note that the 6 in the first line of code refers to the number of columns to create and the 3:6 in the last line of code refers to the column numbers to be converted to numeric.

```
d <- as.data.frame(matrix(scan(textConnection(s), what = ""),, 6, byrow = TRUE),
       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
d[3:6] <- lapply(d[3:6], as.numeric)
```

giving:

```
> d
       V1      V2          V3          V4   V5      V6
1 name_01 name_02 0.000573033 0.001268718 0.45 6.5e-01
2 name_03 name_04 0.003433430 0.001243536 0.33 7.5e-09
```

**3)**  Here is another approach.  We read in the data, pick out the data representing the first resulting column and then the second resulting column and then reread it, setting double quote as the comment character, so that the name rows of the input are omitted.

```
L <- readLines(textConnection(s))
data.frame(Name1 = L[c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)], Name2 = L[c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)],
 read.table(text = L, comment = '"'))
```

giving:

```
     Name1     Name2          V1          V2   V3      V4
1 "name_01" "name_02" 0.000573033 0.001268718 0.45 6.5e-01
2 "name_03" "name_04" 0.003433430 0.001243536 0.33 7.5e-09
```

**Updates**  Added additional solutions, made some minor improvements and added clarification.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Grothendieck